# How to force browser(app) to save login and password for autofill

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obqwge` and `http://m.glonasssoft.ru/test/www/index.html#/login`.
I want to help the user via autofill but its works unpredictably, on some mobile devices it asks, on some not, and it completely ignores on IOS. So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use **localStorage**:

see http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/

Or a service **$localstorage**:

```
 angular.module('angular.localstorage', [])

    .factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function ($window) {
            return {
                set: function (key, value) {
                    $window.localStorage[key] = value;
                },
                get: function (key, defaultValue) {
                    return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
                },
                setObject: function (key, value) {
                    $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
                },
                getObject: function (key) {
                    if ($window.localStorage[key])
                        return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key]);
                    else
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }])
```

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to store usernames and passwords in localstorage?

Comment: I thought about that but yes its totaly unsecure and not acceptable

Comment: Don't forget that here localStorage is protected by the app sandbox / permissions... You are in a Cordova app not in the browser

Comment: Unless you’re making an OS, a browser or a password manager you have no business storing passwords in plaintext for any reason, ever.

Answer (score 0):

After login success you can save username and password to browser local storage.
And try retrieve same details next time on wards when user want login again.

Comment: Storing plaintext passwords is always bad bad bad.

Comment: but this mobile app and question about functionality which is not supported by browser.

Comment: Autofill is not supported by the browser (answering his question). You're suggesting an alternative that creates security risks.

Comment: it is mobile app using ionic framework.using localstorage in cross platform is min risk.

Answer (score 0):

No. Autofill is not a web technology, but a browser technology that most browsers happen to implement. You could store the username and/or password in localstorage or a cookie, but that is a security risk. I suggest you just let the browsers handle it.